# ListView ignores parts of the style of item templates

Tags: listview, winrt-xaml

### Issue description

I've stacked a few TextBlock elements using a regular StackPanel (in a DataTemplate).

When using it as ContentTemplate of a ContentControl, the layout appears as expected. However, if I use the DataTemplate as ItemTemplate of a ListView, some properties are simply ignored (TextLineBounds, but also Margin).

In the following screenshot, I've placed a ContentControl and a ListView with one item next to each other to illustrate the problem. To make the issue more obvious, I've included colored grids to the left of the TextBlocks.

[image: ContentControl on the left (style ok) vs ItemTemplate on the right side (TextLineBounds property is ignored)]

### Things I've tried

I've tried several approaches using Blend. Switching out the ItemContainerStyle, ItemsPanel and ControlTemplate which didn't help.
I could use an ItemsControl and do selection, etc. by hand but I'd like to avoid that.

### Reproduce the issue

The following UserControl can be used to reproduce the issue in a blank winrt project.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ListViewRepro.DropInRepro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="60"
    d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <Grid Width="150">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Height="18" Background="Yellow" />
                    <Grid Height="14" Background="Orange" />
                    <Grid Height="10" Background="GreenYellow" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Header"
                               TextLineBounds="TrimToBaseline" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14.6" Text="Subheader"
                               TextLineBounds="TrimToBaseline" />
                    <TextBlock>Title</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
            <x:String>dummy item</x:String>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Why is there a `Grid` inside of your `ListView`?

Comment: Otherwise, I can see that. It could be a bug. I'll ask around.

Comment: BTW, it renders fine in an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I noticed the BaselineOffset has a different value in these two cases...

Comment: @FilipSkakun The grid was the simplest item I could think of that causes the ListView to display an item. Now I'd use <x:String>test</x:String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `FontFamily` is different in a `ListViewItem` (it's "Segoe UI" as opposed to "Global User Interface"), so if you want it to work the same in both cases - you need to specify the font explicitly as either "Segoe UI" or "Global User Interface" and it will work the same.

Seems like the `BaselineOffset` is one of the differences between these two fonts.

Comment: I needed to (re)set the default FontSize to 10.6666. This - in conjunction with setting the FontFamily - fixed my issue.